# sublimetext build output not showing

Tags: python

I am learning webscraping with python using selenium and chromedriver.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('http://python.org')

html_con=driver.page_source

print('html_con')
```

just the url gets open but sublime text does not show the html in build output

Comment: Are you sure `html_con` is not empty?

Answer (score 1):

remove quotation marks around the 'html_con' in the print statement like this.

```
print(html_con)
```

otherwise you are just telling the interpreter to print the string 'html_con'.

Answer (score 0):

```
print('html_con')
```

that's just going to print >> html_con as wrapping that in quotes is saying print this string rather than the object html_con. This worked for me using Sublime3